# How does the cone look from front view?

Tags: geometry, dual-cone, convex-cone

I have a customized cone and I only have information about top and side view of that cone.

Top and Side view of Cone

[image: Cone views]

Questions:

1. How does the cone look from the front view?
2. How can I plot it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use GeoGebra.